# Will IE7 .msi push-install via GPO cause problems with current IE8?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

My company (finally!) are upgrading from Internet Explorer 6 to Internet Explorer 7. We plan on pushing the installation via GPO. However, some laptops and/or workstations in the office are already running Internet Explorer 8.

My question: Will doing the above push-install cause any problems with the already-installed Internet Explorer 8?

Note: I am *not* looking for a way to downgrade IE8 to IE7; I just want to push-install IE7 for computers still running IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Multiple versions of Internet Explorer installed is not supported as can be done with Microsoft Office.

What can be done is to create a virtualized package that has the version of IE that you need.

It's worth noting that appvirt vendors may not support virtualizing Internet Explorer as an application, as Microsoft considers that "part of the operating system" and not really an application.

**Running multiple versions of Internet Explorer on a single instance of Windows is unsupported**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020599

**Solutions for Virtualizing Internet Explorer**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9242

Comment: I just tried pushing IE7 (.msi generated using IEAK7) via GPO to a test workstation already having IE8. It doesn't seem to install, so I guess it's safe?